# I am trying to set my Flutter app as an option for sharing a picture (android)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-packages

imagine trying to share an image.. a prompt will open with app icons where the image will be shared to. I want my app to be an option for sharing an image, so that i can further send the picture to my pc in the background. any ideas?

I searched online for a package, but i only found something for sharing out of the app (wrong direction)

regards

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822054/how-to-share-an-image-from-gallery-with-my-flutter-app

Answer (score 2):

You mean explicit intent on android. That is something huge.

As of now, there is no dart processes or methods and also no package for handling explicit intent. That is incoming intent.

The only solution is creating the for the native android platform using kotlin or java

use the following link

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Types) to understand more about them before using it.